# Thread-safe string buffer variables in C++ DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, string, thread-safety

I am writing a Win32 DLL in MSVC++2010 with exported functions. Some of those functions return filenames as `LPCSTR`. Because I sometimes need to fiddle with strings before, I am currently using a global buffer variable of length 32184 which should cover any filename that can occur in Windows which I then always initialize and return where a string is needed.

My boss uses this library from a VB6 legacy app. He now informed me that he needs it to be thread-safe: unfortunately for me, due to VB6's event-driven behaviour, it can happen that a function is called in my library even if another function has not yet returned. This, of course, means that I cannot rely on a single internal buffer but have to create one every time I need one and then return it.

2 Questions:

1. I rely heavily on Windows API functions such as `FindFirstFile` and Boost functions from the `filesystem` and `regex` libraries. Can I assume that they are all thread-safe?
2. If I have to create a new buffer on the heap every time I want to return a string, where do I free the memory again?

Comment: what you need is not thread safety but reentrancy safety

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Windows API functions are generally thread-safe, with certain limitations (eg, you cannot `FindNextFile` on the same handle from two threads at the same time, but you can with two different handles). For boost functions, consult the documentation, but generally speaking filesystem/regex functions should be safe as long as you don't use the same object between two threads at the same time.
2. You will have to have the VB6 app call back to free the string when it's done with it. You may also want to consider writing your DLL as a COM library; BSTRs returned from COM calls will be automatically freed by VB6 when they're no longer needed.

Comment: One point to add, I don't think you need to use COM in order to benefit from `BSTR`. You can return `BSTR` from an ordinary DLL and surely the VB6 code will free it happily.

Comment: @David, could be, but I've not worked with VB6 enough to be sure in that respect. I _do_ know it respects normal COM allocation rules, though, so it seemed like safe advice to go with. Plus you don't need to explicitly write out your imports on the VB6 side.

Comment: @David: I don't think this will work. VB6 generally treats strings which do not come from a COM interface as multibyte C strings and then converts them to BSTR internally. I can only declare `function() As String`, the rest is automatic. How should I tell it to expect a BSTR here?

Answer (score 1):

The VB6 code is most probably single threaded. The re-entrancy is presumably limited to the VB6 code.  The VB6 code can't inject re-entrant events into the C++ code.  So long as the C++ code does not call back into the VB6 code then the C++ code itself will not be called in re-entrant fashion.

If these presumptions are correct then your current code with a single global buffer will operate correctly.  That said you would be better off switching to `BSTR` in my view because it would allow for future linking against caller's that were multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TLS for allocation the string:

```
const int string_size = 1024; // string size 
DWORD idTlsString = 0;


// use this function to get the string which you will use to return to VB
char* GetTheString()
{
    return (char*)TlsGetValue(idTlsString);
}

// Dll init function
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  DWORD fdwReason,
  LPVOID lpvReserved
)
{
   switch( fdwReason )
   {
       // allocate TSL
       case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
          idTlsString = TlsAlloc();
       break;

       // allocate the srting
       case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
          TlsSetValue(idTlsString, (LPVOID)new char[string_size] );
       break;

       // free the string
       case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
          delete[] (char*)TlsGetValue(idTlsString);
       break;

       // release TLS
       case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
          TlsFree(idTlsString);
       break;

   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: it sounds like the problem is reentrant calls rather than calls from different threads so this won't work. Plus thread local storage is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I am quite sure (since the global variable was used in the problem) that after C++ call the resulted string is copied into a VB String which makes it safe for reentrant calls in single threaded environment. With TLS I only made it safe for multi threaded calls and nothing more. And it is a quite new for me that using TLS is bad idea. TLS allows you to write lock free code. Since when this is a bad thing?

Comment: TLS is a form of shared global state and has many of the same drawbacks as true global variables. Stack based variables are always to be preferred. Actually regarding the actual problem I bet the boss's code is single threaded. And the re-entrancy is only within the realms of the VB. In which case the original code using global variables is probably correct. My previous comment assumed that the C++ DLL could be called in re-entrant fashion but that would only be possible if it called back to VB.